# Substring isn't retrieving the correct letter

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnMono_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMono.Click
        Dim full As String = Me.txtNamw.Text
        Dim Enter As Integer
        Dim LastEnter As Integer

        Dim firstI As String
        Dim secondI As String
        Dim thirdI As String

        Enter = full.IndexOf("") 'Finds the first space
        LastEnter = full.LastIndexOf("") 'Finds the last space

        Dim secondhalf As String = full.Substring(Enter, LastEnter)
        Dim thirdhalf As String = full.Substring(LastEnter, full.Length)

        firstI = full.Chars(0)
        secondI = secondhalf.Chars(0)
        thirdI = thirdhalf.Chars(0)

        Me.lblAnswer.Text = String.Concat(firstI, secondI, thirdI)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have to create a program for school so when the first name, the second name, and the middle name is inputted the initials of all the 3 names come up. I'm unsure why on why this isn't working AT ALL. I'm trying to separate each name and then get their first intial but it isn't working. I new to VB.NET.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want `...IndexOf("")` to do?  Set breakpoints and debug your code - you will learn about how code executes and it is an essential part of programming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: @Plutonix IndexOf(" ") is supposed to find the position of the space and this helps me separate the strings.

Comment: Is that what the code posted shows? `""` is an empty string, not a space (`" "`)  you can also simply split it using...split:  `Dim parts = theFullname.Split(" ")`

Comment: @Plutonix Could you give an example? I don't know how to use split, and if I would like to find where the space is what would I need to do?

Comment: I rather think I just did.  Its right there and also [right here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `still not working` is a very poor problem description. Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]  Both SubString and Split work fine when used correctly.

Comment: @Plutonix, My apologies, I have figured out how to get the first two initials working, however the final initial is coming up as "Nothing" when I set breakpoints. Am I using "length" incorrectly?

Comment: What you are doing is *manually* splitting the string at the space.  `String.Split` will do that for you, the array returned will be the parts of the string - the names - whether there are 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @Plutonix Oh, that was very helpful and I think you just solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Plutonix said, it is easy with .Split() method.

```
    Dim fName, mName, lName As Char
    Dim names() As String = s.Split()
    fName = names(0).Chars(0)

    mName = names(1).Chars(0)

    lName = names(2).Chars(0)
    Console.WriteLine(fName & " " & mName & " " & lName)
```